# Regex match regex with 1 statement but not another

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to match this regex

```
(sq.*f|gla|livingarea)
```

but I want it to not have the letters 'pr' anywhere in there.

so things like sqftpr or pricesqft etc dont' match.

I can prevent pricesqft with negative lookbehind

```
(?<!pr)(sq.*f|gla|livingarea)
```

I can't get the negative look behind to work with a negative look ahead. Any idea how I can get both?

```
(?<!pr)(sq.*f|g.?la|livingarea)(?!pr)
```

Any idea how I can block on both'pr' on both sides?

Comment: Is it a hard limitation that you can call the regex-match function only once? If not, you could solve it quite easily by combining the existing regex call with a second one solely excluding the /pr/ matches.

Comment: `sqftpr or pricesqft` are not matched by your regex, so your example is pretty bad :) guess you mean `sqprf` which shouldn't match the `pr` with `.*`...

Comment: Okay, understand... Take care with the wording "match", cause in Java (for example) `a match` does mean, that the whole string needs to MATCH the pattern - an implicit `^PATTERN$` so to say - What you mean, is java's `find`, hence `pricesqft` is **found** as  `sqft`, which you like to avoid.

Comment: No I want javascript /{regex pattern}/.test() to evaluate to false for pricesqft and sqftprice but true for sqft or squarefeet

Comment: That's the equal thing :) In java it's `match()` vs `find()` - in JS it's `match()` vs `test()` - so use `match()` rather than `test()` and you are good, except for the case where `pr` is covered by the `.*` of the pattern: `sqprf` - if that's a possible option at all.

Comment: ps.: syntax is `str.match(/pattern/)` rather than `/pattern/.test(str)`

Comment: @dognose I understand how regex is used ... but the pattern above doesn't work since it returns matches even when 'price' is in it. Without a proper pattern the above things won't work as intended within my code ... which is why I posted a question about having a proper matching pattern.

Comment: Then please describe more detailed what you like to achieve. Is the string you want to `find` inside other strings like `I have 258 squarefeet of space` or is the *value you check against* already cut down to a clear start/end? `258 squarefeet`. If you want to extract information from the first case, you need lookarounds. If you just want to validate the second-case, your pattern along with `match()` rather than `test()` would be enough.

Comment: You should include Sample input, and desired output examples. (What should and shouldn't match)

Comment: I  was able to find it throwing stuff around for another 30 min posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(?=^((?!pr).)*$).*(?=(sq.*f|g.?la|livingarea))
This appears to be the answer, a positive lookahead (essentially an and) that looks for 'pr' and nots it with what I want to match to the right.